# Read data from plist

Tags: swift3, plist

I'm trying to convert my own app from Objective-C to Swift 3.
Try is a sample of my plist:

[elements.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug1vp.png)

I'm trying this code I found in another similar question:

```
  //get the path of the plist file
    guard let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "elements", ofType: "plist") else { return }

    print("plistPath:", plistPath)


    //load the plist as data in memory
    guard let plistData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: plistPath) else { return }

    print("plistData:", plistData)


    //use the format of a property list (xml)
    var format = PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.xml
    //convert the plist data to a Swift Dictionary
    guard let  plistDict = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, options: .mutableContainersAndLeaves, format: &format) as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }

    print("plistDict:", plistDict)


    //access the values in the dictionary
    if let value = plistDict["DescrizioneEsercizio"] as? String {
        //do something with your value
        print(value)
    }
```

Please, let me know how can I import data from plist and access a single field in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the plist. It contains an array of dictionaries.

```
guard let  plistDicts = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, options: .mutableContainersAndLeaves, format: &format) as? [[String : AnyObject]] 
     else { 
          return 
     }
 // See how it is casted to an Array of Dictionaries ([[String : AnyObject]]) here
```

Now you can iterate over your dicts and do what you need:

```
for dict in plistDicts {
    if let value = plistDict["DescrizioneEsercizio"] as? String {
        //do something with your value
        print(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I simply want to print the first value of my plist (item0, DescrizioneEsercizio), what is the code to do it?

Comment: You have to think yourself a little. `plistDicts` is an array of dictionaries. How would you get the first dictionary in Obj-C? `plistDicts.first` or `plistDicts[0]`.